gcloud storage cp is not working for larger files
I am trying to use gcloud storage cp command for copying large files to gcp bucket. The command is working fine for smaller files. But it gives permission issue for larger files.
gcloud storage cp test.csv   gs://bkt/testbucket/file.csv --project projectid
  Completed files 0 | 0B
ERROR: (gcloud.storage.cp) User [serviceaccount.com] does not have permission to access b instance [bkt] (or it may not exist): serviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.buckets.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).

The error msg doesn't make sense. But I have tried reducing the file size and it is working fine.

what is the best way to transfer a file arond 50 gb from local to gcs bucket

please also try by considering a different and better internet connection .

When posting a problem like yours, include specific details on what works and what does not. Are there any org constraints or other policies that can affect access?

Add the --log-http flag to your gcloud command and share more verbose error details please.

1st please make sure that the bucket exist
then you can try by giving the require permission for example
gsutil iam ch user:john.doe@example.com:objectCreator \
              domain:www.my-domain.org:objectViewer gs://ex-bucket

or as require
 gsutil iam ch \
    serviceAccount:john.doe@example.com:objectAdmin \
    gs://bkt

please see granting-full-gcs-bucket-permissions-to-a-gcp-service-account and iam#ch-examples
you should then consider following
quotas#objects

This limit applies regardless of write method, including object
composition, resumable uploads, and multipart uploading. While it is
possible to upload the full 5 TiB in a single upload request, such
long-running uploads are more likely to experience failures; resumable
uploads are the recommended method for uploading large objects.

resumable-uploads#behavior

The gcloud CLI uses resumable uploads in the gcloud storage cp and
gcloud storage rsync commands when uploading data to Cloud Storage. If
your upload is interrupted, you can resume it by running the same
command that you used to start the upload. When resuming such an
upload that includes multiple files, use the --no-clobber flag to
prevent re-uploading files that already completed successfully.

additionally as you said that (an if all is correct) you been able to upload the small size files and only the problem is occurring with the lager file/s.
i dough there might be something happening in background and most probably it could be the deny-policies  ,which worth considering .

How deny policies work
Deny policies are made up of deny rules. Each deny rule specifies the
following:
1.A set of principals that are denied permissions

2.The permissions that the principals are denied, or unable to use

3.Optional: The condition that must be true for the permission to be denied

When a principal is denied a permission, they can't do anything that
requires that permission, regardless of the IAM roles they've been
granted. This is because IAM always checks relevant deny policies
before checking relevant allow policies. For details, see policy
evaluation.

you might want to see conditions-overview

In most cases that kind of behavior (gcloud storage cp stopped working for bigger files with something like permissions issue) will be related to missing "storage.buckets.get" permissions and multi-region bucket.
For bigger files gcloud by default automatically switch to parallel composite upload for better performance and I assume it start listing under the hood buckets (in different region) and instead of provide clear error it throws that unclear message.
And if you for smaller files won't notice any problems that message could be really confusing.
More about parallel composite uploads: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/parallel-composite-uploads
